Remove row group based on conditions
I need help with my SQL query:
select      
    p.LookupCode as customers,
    m.LookupCode as materials,
    lp.lookupcode as licensePlates,
    lc.name as locations
from        
    dbo.LicensePlates lp
join        
    dbo.LicensePlateContents lpc on lp.id = lpc.LicensePlateId 
join        
    dbo.Lots l on lpc.LotId = l.id
join        
    dbo.Materials m on  l.materialId = m.id
join        
    dbo.Projects p on m.projectId = p.id
join        
    dbo.LocationContainers lc on lp.LocationId = lc.id
where       
    p.LookupCode = 'Neighbor'
    and lp.Archived = 0
    and m.LookupCode in ('HVN-AM1-16001-4', 'ACORN-STAND-BLACK-1')

This query returns this results:
customers   material            licensePlates        locations
--------------------------------------------------------------
Neighbor    ACORN-STAND-BLACK-1 994872ILP            DOCK
Neighbor    ACORN-STAND-BLACK-1 995101ILP            DOCK
Neighbor    ACORN-STAND-BLACK-1 997927ILP            DOCK
Neighbor    ACORN-STAND-BLACK-1 997969ILP            DOCK
Neighbor    HVN-AM1-16001-4     430-015-100-02       430-015-100-02
Neighbor    HVN-AM1-16001-4     986053ILP            DOCK
Neighbor    HVN-AM1-16001-4     986055ILP            DOCK
Neighbor    HVN-AM1-16001-4     986848ILP            DOCK
Neighbor    HVN-AM1-16001-4     986850ILP            DOCK

What I need is when a group of materials example this HVN-AM1-16001-4 has a group of Locations of DOCK and also the other which is NOT DOCK but shows like 430-015-100-02 but this can change to other numbers but same format of example 111-111-111-11 but when a group of material has DOCK and at the same time this format numbers of 111-111-111-11 then this whole group should not show in the results
Dor material ACORN-STAND-BLACK-1 which you see all locations showing as DOCK only then this is what I only need to show in my query results.

Please provide a [mre] with sample data, desired results, your attempt, and emphasis on minimal i.e. you don't need to provide your complex production query to illustrate the problem, cut it down to the simplest example you can

Something like: select * from (select *, min(locations) over(partition by customers, material) as mn, max(locations) over(partition by customers, material) as mx from yourtable t) x where x.mn = mx and x.mn = 'DOCK'

with x as (
    select      p.LookupCode as customers,
                m.LookupCode as materials,
                lp.lookupcode as licensePlates,
                lc.name as locations,
                max(iif(lc.name = 'DOCK', 0, 1))
                over (partition by m.LookupCode) as blah
    
    from        dbo.LicensePlates lp
    join        dbo.LicensePlateContents lpc on lp.id = lpc.LicensePlateId 
    join        dbo.Lots l on lpc.LotId = l.id
    join        dbo.Materials m on  l.materialId = m.id
    join        dbo.Projects p on m.projectId = p.id
    join        dbo.LocationContainers lc on lp.LocationId = lc.id
    
    
    where       p.LookupCode ='Neighbor'
    and         lp.Archived=0
    and         m.LookupCode in('HVN-AM1-16001-4','ACORN-STAND-BLACK-1')
)
select * from x where blah = 0

we project a bit col: "0" for "DOCK" and "1" for everything else, and take its max over the group of LookupCode and call it "blah" - if this value is not 0 then something other than "DOCK" appears in the group. we can't just put this expression in the where clause because SQL Server only allows window functions in the select clause, so we use a common table expression to workaround that limitation.

Assuming this is a valid answer, a little explanation would be helpful.

is it the correct answer, thank you.

I have extended your transformation with a CTE to get the desired output
WITH MaterialLocations AS (
    SELECT        
        p.LookupCode AS customers,
        m.LookupCode AS materials,
        lp.lookupcode AS licensePlates,
        lc.name AS locations
    FROM        
        dbo.LicensePlates lp
    JOIN        
        dbo.LicensePlateContents lpc ON lp.id = lpc.LicensePlateId 
    JOIN        
        dbo.Lots l ON lpc.LotId = l.id
    JOIN        
        dbo.Materials m ON l.materialId = m.id
    JOIN        
        dbo.Projects p ON m.projectId = p.id
    JOIN        
        dbo.LocationContainers lc ON lp.LocationId = lc.id
    WHERE        
        p.LookupCode = 'Neighbor'
        AND lp.Archived = 0
        AND m.LookupCode IN ('HVN-AM1-16001-4', 'ACORN-STAND-BLACK-1')
),
MaterialGrouped AS (
    SELECT 
        materials,
        MAX(CASE WHEN locations = 'DOCK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS has_dock,  -- 1 if any "DOCK" location exists
        MAX(CASE WHEN locations LIKE '%[0-9]%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS has_numbered_location -- 1 if any numbered location exists
    FROM 
        MaterialLocations
    GROUP BY 
        materials
)
SELECT 
    m.customers,
    m.materials,
    m.licensePlates,
    m.locations
FROM 
    MaterialLocations m
JOIN 
    MaterialGrouped mg ON m.materials = mg.materials
WHERE 
    (mg.has_dock = 1 AND mg.has_numbered_location = 0)  -- Exclude materials that have both types of locations
ORDER BY
    m.materials, m.locations;

Explanation :
MAX(CASE WHEN locations = 'DOCK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END):This expression checks whether any "DOCK" location exists for each material.
MAX(CASE WHEN locations LIKE '%[0-9]%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END): This checks whether any location matches the numbered location pattern (i.e., a string containing numbers).
Lastly the where clause will only return materials that have DOCK as a location and no numbered location
